# Como usar um valor de um dicionário para chamar uma função específica em Python?

Tags: python, string, funções, dicionário

Estou tentando usar um dicionário para identificar cada função a um valor, e chamá-las ao longo do programa. Meu código está abaixo (exemplo):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
menuOpt = {
    1 : "valor",
}
#Main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Valor"
    menuOpt[1]()
def valor():
    x = 8
    y = 7
    o = x*y
    print o
```

Porém, quando executo-o, recebo o seguinte erro:

```
Valor
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "teste.py", line 8, in <module>
    menuOpt[1]()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Aparentemente, ele diz que não posso chamar a função usando a string que defino como valor de uma entrado do dicionário. Existe uma forma de contornar essa situação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei exatamente o que você quer fazer, mas a resposta mais simples para você é:

```
# nome = menuOpt[1]
globals().get(nome)()
```

Porém é bom não deixar o código morrer se o nome não existir ou se o nome não é 'chamável', isso pode ser alcançado (usando a abordagem: [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) 'é mais fácil pedir perdão que permissão') assim:

```
# nome = menuOpt[1]
try: 
   globals().get(nome)()
except TypeError:
   pass
```

Porém já precisei fazer isso para um sistema de plugins em que era necessário o pacote completo (`from pacote.x.y.z import funcao`), assim eu precisava de algo mais elaborado, como:

```
def getattrfull(path):
    """
    Obtem um atributo de um caminho separado por '.' simulando um `import`

    Exemplo para simular 'from os import name as sistema':
    >>> sistema = getattrfull('os.name')
    >>> sistema
    'posix'

    Funciona para funcoes/classes/etc:
    >>> decode = getattrfull('json.loads')
    >>> decode('[1, 2, 3, 4]')
    [1, 2, 3, 4]

    Se o modulo ou funcao nao existir ele retorna 'None'
    >>> getattrfull('eu.nao.existo')
    None
    """

    # Primeiro tem que separar o modulo da funcao/classe/qualquercoisa
    # XXX: o codigo só funciona se tiver ".", ou seja, não pega nomes 
    #      locais ao arquivo atual, para fazer comportamento semelhante use:
    #      >>> globals().get(nome)
    module_name, attr_name = path.rsplit(".", 1)

    # importar modulo
    try:
        module = __import__(module_name, locals(), globals(), [str(attr_name)])
    except ImportError:
        return None

    # procurar pelo atributo
    try:
        attr = getattr(module, attr_name)
    except AttributeError:
        return None

    return attr
```

Answer (score 2):

De acordo com [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/834451/2637754) no SOEn. Utilize:

```
locals()["nomedafuncao"]()
```

ou

```
globals()["nomedafuncao"]()
```

No seu caso, seria:

```
locals()[menuOpt[1]]()
```

Answer (score 2):

É simples, em vez de colocar uma string, coloque o nome da função. Além disso, você pode estruturar o seu programa um pouco melhor:

```
def valor():
    """ Função a ser chamada """
    print('valor')

menuOpt = {
    1 : valor,
}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    menuOpt[1]()
```